# Should it be possible to export a constexpr function pointer from a cpp module?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

I'm trying to export a constexpr function pointer from a cpp module, but Visual Studio (16.9.0 preview 4.0) gives me an internal compiler error. When I remove the second `constexpr`, everything works just fine. Am I trying to do something that's not allowed?

```
export module MyModule;

constexpr int twice(int x)
{
    return x * 2;
}

export namespace my
{
    constexpr int (*func)(int) = &twice;
}
```

Comment: ICE is always compiler bug, even if code is ill-formed.

Comment: Notice that it is `func` which is constexpr, There is no type `constexpr int (*)(int)`.

Comment: While this is obviously a compiler bug of some sort, I'm curious as to why you can't just put the function in your namespace instead of using a function pointer.

Comment: @Jarod42 Note that ICE isn't always a **standards violation**, but is always a **bug**.  Under the standard, an ICE's "I crashed" message qualifies as a diagnostic message, and the standard cares nothing about the quality of the message.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is valid: presumably MSVC is confused by the default **internal** linkage associated with a const variable, but that doesn’t apply to **exported** variables.  (It shouldn’t apply in an importable module unit at all, since the historical reason of allowing multiple inclusion of named constants doesn’t apply there.  I may file an issue.)